# Timer in Java that doesn't pause the program?

Tags: java, timer

I was wondering if there was a form of timer that I can use that doesn't pause all of my code `Thread.sleep(ms)` is not what I need because it pauses all of my code.

EDIT: Okay, I think I misworded that. Here's my edit:
Is there a way to measure a certain amount of time in Java without pausing my `main` method?

Comment: see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

Comment: What are you trying to do???

Answer (score 1):

I like to using `Executors` class. It have a nice method that is `newScheduledThreadPool`. It gives you an `ScheduledExecutorService` instance, which have a lot of scheduling methods.

Check it out here here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
scheduler.schedule(threadToExecute, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This code will start `threadToExecute thread` after 10 seconds, without pausing your main thread.

Comment: TimeUnit is not a class that can be imported.

Comment: I didn't get it. `import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;`

Comment: Thanks. Control + Shift + O wasn't working. Also, what is threadToExecute? Could you please provide an example.

Comment: One more thing: It says that the first parameter is a Runnable or a Callable. How do I use these?

Comment: It is the effective thread to execute. Most of the times it is a class that extends `Thread`. Please take a look at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which Frameworks you use. A pretty generic way would be to start a new `Thread`, pause that Thread via Thread.sleep(ms) and then do whatever you want to do after that delay, but of course that requires a little bit of care because of concurrency issues.

Comment: I am sure java has some builtin timer api

Comment: You are right, of course, there is, java.util.Timer, for example.

Comment: But, is there like a something that can measure time without pausing the program?

Comment: Neither an extra Thread not Timer (which does something similar) will pause your main Thread and thus not the program...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class. You can attach it to a thread, schedule events, and add delays. What you could do with this is you could create a thread to run along side your main thread and have it run from there. Because they will be on two completely different threads, you don't need to worry about them interfering with each other. To run the other thread, you could create a class that extends `Thread` and run it. Then use the `Timer(String name)` constructor to create a Timer for the thread.